# Variable Not Set When Same Batch Script Run Twice

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch script that is just toggles my python pathing. When I run it a second time, my variable doesn't get set but the string I want it to be set to is echoed onto the console.

First time running the script:

```bat
C:\Users\Hai\Desktop>FOR /F "delims=" %I IN ('Python -V') DO (
setlocal
 set "ver=%I"
)

C:\Users\Hai\Desktop>(
setlocal
 set "ver=Python 3.6.3"
)
```

Second time running same batch file without closing console:

```bat
C:\Users\Hai\Desktop> chPythonVer.bat

C:\Users\Hai\Desktop>FOR /F "delims=" %I IN ('Python -V') DO (
setlocal
 set "ver=%I"
)
Python 2.7.15
```

This is how I'm setting my variable:

```bat
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('Python -V') DO (
    setlocal
    set "ver=%%I"
)

echo the current version pathed is %ver%

SET /P c=would you like to switch to the other version? [y/n] 
IF /I "%c%" EQU "y" (
    IF "%ver%" EQU "Python 3.6.3" (
        endlocal
        set PATH= ...
        echo switched to Python 2.7.15
        pause
    ) ELSE (
        endlocal
        set PATH= ...
        echo switched to Python 3.6.3
        pause
    )   
) ELSE IF /I "%c%" EQU "n" (
    endlocal
    pause
)
```

Comment: You could possibly use [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) instead to choose Python version.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is a bad idea to set variable names to existing environment variable names. i.e `path`

You would also need `delayedexpansion` as you are setting a variable in a code block. So rename `PATH` to `myPATH`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('Python -V') DO (
    set "ver=%%I"
)

echo the current version pathed is %ver%

SET /P c=would you like to switch to the other version? [y/n] 
IF /I "!c!" EQU "y" (
IF "!ver!" EQU "Python 3.6.3" (
    set mypath= ...
    echo switched to Python 2.7.15
    pause
) ELSE (
    set mypath= ...
    echo switched to Python 3.6.3
    pause
)   
    ) ELSE IF /I "!c!" EQU "n" (
   pause
)
```

If however you were looking at actually updating the system path temporarily then, ignore the first comment and you should then set path as:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\whereever\python is\
```

Comment: It's not that easy, the `python -v` presumes it **is** in the path. If you prepend the other version to the path to override you over time get a very long path - so you have to remove the previous version.

Comment: `set "PATH=...` just updates the `PATH` variable for the *current `cmd` session*, so to permanently change it, take a look at the [`setx` command](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl yes, he seems to want it set it locally like that, look at the `setlocal/endlocal` in his script..